# Carregar rota ao clicar no menu dentro um componente (Dashboard)

Tags: javascript, react, adonisjs

Agora estou utilizando o adonis (amo o laravel) e to fazendo o case do ReactJs aqui do blog. mais me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Tenho um dashboard admin, aonde o mesmo possui:

- Header.js (navbar)
- sidebar.js (menu lateral)
- content.js

como faço pra toda vez que clicar em um item de menu ele carrege no content, sem ter que ficar copiando toda essa estrutura em cada page? tipo, fazer um template e todas as rotas carregarem no content?

Hoje meu projetinho esta asssim:

route.js

```
const Routes = () => (


<browserrouter>


<switch>


<route exact="" path="/" component="{Login}"/>


<privateroute path="/app" component="{dashboard}"/>


<privateroute path="/clientes" component="{dashboard}"/>


</switch>


</browserrouter>


)
```

dashboard.js

```
<>
...
<route path="/clientes" component="{Clientes}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar uma biblioteca como a React Router. [Neste site](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/) você encontra um tutorial de como configurar no seu projeto React.

Resumidamente, no componente principal da sua aplicação você deverá adicionar o componente `<BrowserRouter>` e dentro deste serão definidas todas as rotas. O caminho para cada rota e qual componente renderizar serão definidos usando o componente `<Route>`. Conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

<Router>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/news">News</Link>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/news" component={NewsFeed}/>
  </div>
</Router>
```